# Authorize.net ignores default New Order Status

Tags: authorize.net

I have a custom default processing status called Payment Authorized. In addition to setting it to the default order status I also made it the Authorize.net default status. In Direct Post method it works as expected. I do not want to use direct post though and the other Authorize.net method keeps defaulting the order status to Proessing.

Is this the culprit?

```
class Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment extends Mage_Payment_Model_Info
{
  ...
  protected function _authorize($isOnline, $amount)
   {
    // check for authorization amount to be equal to grand total
    $this->setShouldCloseParentTransaction(false);
    $isSameCurrency = $this->_isSameCurrency();
    if (!$isSameCurrency || !$this->_isCaptureFinal($amount)) {
        $this->setIsFraudDetected(true);
    }

    // update totals
    $amount = $this->_formatAmount($amount, true);
    $this->setBaseAmountAuthorized($amount);

    // do authorization
    $order  = $this->getOrder();
    $state  = Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING;
    $status = true;
    if ($isOnline) {
        // invoke authorization on gateway
        $this->getMethodInstance()->setStore($order->getStoreId())->authorize($this, $amount);
    }
```

## tl:dr

My default processing status in Magento is Payment Authorized. My default New Order Status for payment method Authorize.net is the same. When a new order is placed the order instead defaults to *Processing*

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've successfully assigned your new status to the "processing" state.   You can verify this by looking at the `sales_order_status_state` table if necessary to make sure your status and state (processing) are wired up correctly.

#### After that:

1. Go to System --> Configuration --> Sales --> Payment Methods
2. Under "New Order Status" select your new status (see image)
3. Clear Cache

After doing this, my new orders come are set to the correct status (in my case "Waiting Authorization")

[image: Screenshot of Payment methods configuration screen]

I am using Magento EE 1.14.1